# missing Change-Id in commit message footer during push to gerrit

Tags: git, gerrit

Here is my configuration;

on the server:

os: Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.7 (Santiago)

git 2.7.1

gerrit 2.12.2

on the client:

Rational Application Developer v9.0

Egit v4.2

Mylin Reviews Connector: Gerrit v2.9

When I try to push a change to gerrit ("Push upstream") , it fails with the missing change id error message.

I did some googling, and installed the commit-msg hook in the .git/hooks directory of the local repo.

The change id is there in the commit message, but there is a bunch of comments added by the (mylin client I guess) after that.

Please advise. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change-Id has to be in the footer (i.e. last line of commit message). You should fix your commit message with

```
git commit --amend
```

You should move the Change-Id to the end or remove all unnecessary content including change-id - it should be regenerated during amend with the hook you have installed.

---

Commit that is valid in Gerrit should contain at least the first line of the message (the subject) and the Change-Id in the footer. From the [Change Ids docs](https://git.eclipse.org/r/Documentation/user-changeid.html):

> To be picked up by Gerrit, a Change-Id line must be in the footer (last paragraph) of a commit message

i.e.:

```
Improve foo widget by attaching a bar

Change-Id: Ic8aaa0728a43936cd4c6e1ed590e01ba8f0fbf5b
```

I believe that if the commit message contains the change id only (no subject) it is not valid.

Comment: Thanks for your message. I did the "git commit --amend" and tried with just the change id line in the commit message, then did the "push upstream" from the eclipse "Git Repositories" view, still got the same message. Or am I t push using command line? There is a amend option in the eclipse egit/mylin "git staging" view. I tried that as well to no avail. Is there a way to change the automatically generated commit message (ie all the comments etc)

Comment: The issue is solved now. In addition to the change id line, another line is required above it. Thanks for your help.